# How to change menu URLs to hashes?

Tags: menus

I'm building a fullpage Wordpress site. Meaning the pages are not separate URLs, they are accessed through the same URL. Something like [deuxhuithuit.com](http://deuxhuithuit.com).

So I have a menu that the admin creates by selecting different pages. Wordpress generates the unordered list of links with URLs like `http://mysite.com/page-slug`. I want my theme to change those links into hashes to the same URL `http://mysite.com#page-slug.

Any ideas?

Comment: how are you generating the list of links, a nav menu?

Comment: I think you should add custom links in your menu. Each section must have `post-id` so you can add like `http://mysite.com#post-id`

Comment: @Milo, right, a nav menu

Comment: @Roberthue, yeah I know that. But I want the admin to easily edit the menu without the need of typing the slug. He's not very techie and he'll be editing the menu quite frequently.

Comment: you could use a custom walker function to update the output of the urls

Comment: @karpstrucking yeah. That's what I ended up doing, check my answer below. I thought there would be a nicer way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I solved it so far.

```
class themename_walker_nav_menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
     function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
        $slug = get_post( $item->object_id )->post_name;
        $item->url = "#{$slug}";
        return parent::start_el( $output, $item, $depth, $args  );
    }
}
```